# OSGi - Candidate permutation failed due to a conflict between imports

Tags: osgi

I am in a situation where my Felix OSGi container will not start properly after deploying groovy via:

> obr:deploy "Groovy Scripting Languge"@1.7.3

Managed to deploy & got Groovy stuff running, until I did a restart on my OSGi container...then most of the bundles will not start. FWIW, I am pretty sure Groovy is not the cause even though there's a typo in its bundle name. :-)

After some troubleshooting, turning on Felix's wire logging (thank god!), i noticed this (among all the other failed bundles, similar cause):

```
2011-04-03 16:26:43,108 DEBUG [FelixStartLevel] felix.wire - Candidate permutation failed due to a conflict between imports; will try another if possible. (org.apache.felix.framework.resolver.ResolveException: Unable to resolve module org.apache.felix.http.bundle [36.0] because it is exposed to package 'org.osgi.framework' from org.apache.felix.framework [0] and com.springsource.org.aspectj.tools [47.0] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.apache.felix.http.bundle [36.0]
    import: (&(package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.3.0))
     |
    export: package=org.osgi.framework
  org.apache.felix.framework [0]

Chain 2:
  org.apache.felix.http.bundle [36.0]
    import: (&(package=org.osgi.service.log)(version>=1.3.0))
     |
    export: package=org.osgi.service.log; uses:=org.osgi.framework
  osgi.cmpn [15.0]
    import: (&(package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
     |
    export: package=org.osgi.framework
  com.springsource.org.aspectj.tools [47.0])
```

Seems like both `o.a.felix.framework` and `c.s.o.aspectj.tools` are exporting `o.osgi.framework`.

I am able to get things running again by removing bundle id 47 (`c.s.o.aspectj.tools`), but yet to check if there's other implications. Feels wrong because I removed `c.s.o.aspectj.tools` but it was indicated as required (or optional) for Groovy by the OBR repository. In fact, it was installed via the obr:deploy command for Groovy.

Feels like `c.s.o.aspectj.tools` should not be exporting `o.osgi.framework`, but that's just a guess as i do not use aspectj tools stuff.

Question: What is the proper way to resolve such issues without resorting to educated guesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, `c.s.o.aspectj.tools` should not be export `org.osgi.framework`, but apparently it does. To be precise, I checked version `1.6.8`, and that has the following export statement:

```
org.osgi.framework;version="1.6.8.RELEASE"
```

Furthermore, it does not *import* `org.osgi.framework`. This is plain *wrong*, and I'd say it's worth a bugreport with the Spring team; if you export, you should usually import, and I can't think of a valid reason to tag `osg.osgi.framework` with a different version than it actually has.

How can you get around this for now? The problem with the two resolution chains can be resolved by wiring both `http` and `cmpn` to the same `framework` package; perhaps even a simple `osgi:refresh` in the shell could help you, since the declared version (`1.6.8.RELEASE`) is within the import ranges of both `http` and `cmpn`, by accident.

If you don't really need the `aspectj` stuff, I would leave it out.

Comment: thanks @angelo! found this https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/EBR-407 bug reported that seems to be related. i'll just remove aspectj for now.